# No sound over HDMI with Nvidia GPU

Tags: debian, audio, nvidia, alsa, hdmi

Disclaimer: yes I know there are tons of posts on this and other forums about pretty much the same. I have been through *many* of them and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Install: Debian Buster freshly installed on Lenovo P15 Laptop with Nvidia discrete GPU. The Laptop is in "discrete GPU only" mode, as per the bios option I enabled.

HDMI: I get video over HDMI to my TV but no sound. It is not the cable, and it is not the TV.

Sound settings: the standard Debian sound settings don't show the HDMI output, even when the cable is plugged and the image is on the TV. pavucontrol does not show it either (only built in option available). I have pulseaudio installed of course. Alsamixer shows 6 S/PDIF cannals for the GPU, all unmuted. Somehow I cannot set their volume though which is weird.

Here are some useful outputs:

aplay -l

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC285 Analog [ALC285 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

lspci -knn|grep -iA2 audio

```
    00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:06c8]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22b8]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f9] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo TU106 High Definition Audio Controller [17aa:22b8]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

I have also read the whole wiki on ALSA, to no avail.

The one odd thing I notice in my setup is that I have no ~/.asoundrc nor /etc/asound.conf.

By the way, I have the Nvidia driver for my GPU, not nouveau, and it is working properly.

What I would like is for the sound to automatically go over the HDMI when the cable is plugged, or that I can somehow choose which output in pavucontrol or in the standard Debian sound settings.

I would be extremely grateful for any help and I will be happy to promptly provide any additional output you guys require.